# How can be components added dynamically in the JDialog?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, jdialog

I am trying to create GUI like given in first picture, but I am not able to do it.[here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6hb0.jpg)
I am getting only one combo1, combo2, combo3 and serialNoLabel instead of 5 [5 is the size of list]

```
    ArrayList<String> list; // the size of the list is 5
    JComboBox combo1[] = new JComboBox[list.size()];
    JComboBox combo2[] = new JComboBox[list.size()];
    JComboBox combo3[] = new JComboBox[list.size()];
    JLabel SerialNoLabel[] = new JLabel[list.size()];
    JPanel masterPanel[] = new JPanel[list.size()];

    JDialog masterDialog =  new JDialog();
    masterDialog.setVisible(true);
    masterDialog.setSize(800, 500);
    masterDialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    masterDialog.setVisible(true);
    for(int j =0; j < list.size(); j++) {
        masterPanel[j] = new JPanel();
        SerialNoLabel[j] = new JLabel(list.get(j));
        masterPanel[j].add(SerialNoLabel[j]);
        combo1[j] = new JComboBox();
        masterPanel[j].add(combo1[j]);
        combo2[j] = new JComboBox();
        masterPanel[j].add(combo2[j]);
        combo3[j] = new JComboBox();
        masterPanel[j].add(combo3[j]);
        masterDialog.add(masterPanel[j]);
        masterDialog.revalidate();
    }
```

Comment: Don't you have a layout for you masterDialog? Also can you print screen what you get? With a quick look I really do believe that it's a layout issue.

Comment: When you add one of the masterPanels to the masterDialog, you're adding it to the center of a BorderLayout.  You're effectively overlaying your masterPanels, so only one shows.  You need to have a mainPanel (JPanel) with a FlowLayout.  You would add the masterPanels to the mainPanel, and finally, add the mainPanel to the masterDialog.

Comment: @LBes I am using MigLayout for masterDialog.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Can you explain me in brief... I am new to swing

Comment: I've not used a MigLayout.  I made an assumption based on your tiny code fragment.  Put a self-contained (don't use the MigLayout), **runnable** example of your problem in your question, and I'll fix it so it produces the GUI in your drawing.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc This is the only code that I have written to create this GUI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it's a layout issue leading your masterPanels to be on top of each other.

So I would do something like this:

```
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
FlowLayout experimentLayout = new FlowLayout();
mainPanel.setLayout(experimentLayout);
for(int j =0; j < list.size(); j++) {
        masterPanel[j] = new JPanel();
        SerialNoLabel[j] = new JLabel(list.get(j));
        masterPanel[j].add(SerialNoLabel[j]);
        combo1[j] = new JComboBox();
        masterPanel[j].add(combo1[j]);
        combo2[j] = new JComboBox();
        masterPanel[j].add(combo2[j]);
        combo3[j] = new JComboBox();
        mainPanel.add(masterPanel[j]);
    }
```

Of course you could other layouts as well. But I believe you want to go for a `FlowLayout`. See the documentation about `FlowLayout` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html).

You can learn more about other layouts [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/layoutlist.html)

Comment: @VarshalDavda sure!

Comment: can you please tell me, how can I add action listeners to this combo boxes? Thanks

Comment: @VarshalDavda that's a totally different question. Look it up online and try to see if you can figure it out. If not ask an other question here.

Comment: @VarshalDavda No problem.